# UTM Ubuntu22.04 of arm64 Booting Configuration Issue

Tags: boot, 22.04, mac, qemu

I'm facing an issue with UTM in MacBook with M2 chips while running the arm64 version of Ubuntu 22.04(from `https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/jammy/daily-live/current/`). I install this iso image in UTM  as usual, but each time I open the virtual machine, it requires a fresh boot(which shows below), causing the loss of data from the previous session. I've tried configuring persistent storage, but it doesn't seem to take effect.

[UTM is booting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02xMX.png)

and the following options is described as below:

[booting options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jheTf.png)

but unfortunately I really don't quiet understand these options...I want to look for guidance on properly configuring booting configrations in UTM to ensure that data and state are retained with each boot.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try ejecting the .iso image after the installation asks you to restart?